# Jquery Mobile 1.4.5 programmatically pagecontainer change not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jqm 1.4.5. for my web app.  I have a problem changing to a page programmatically using the pagecontainer change widget in a certain situation.  I have a home page that is part of the index.html file.  From the home page if I load an external page via jqm ajax method and then from that page have a button that changes back to the home page (via javascript) it fails silently.  However,  it works if the external page has an anchor button with an href="#home_page".

The JS code is being executed. All the id's are correct.

Why does it work using the anchor button but not programmatically with the button tag using the JS code?

What am I doing wrong?

**index.html**

```
<div id="page_home" data-role="page" >
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
     <a href="page_external.html" data-role="button"> load in the external page</a>
</div>
```

**page_external.html**

```
    <div id="page_external" data-role="page" >
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
     <a href="#page_home" data-role="button"> go to home page</a>  <!-- this works -->
     <button  id="mybutton" data-role="button" > go to home page (script)</button> <!-- this does not work -->
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", "#mybutton, function  () {
//this fails silently and does not change the page
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer( "change", "#page_home" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here on SO:

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158294/jquery-mobile-cannot-get-it-to-change-page-using-mobile-changepage)

I was using the wrong syntax.  It should be

```
$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer( "change", $("#page_home" ));
```